# Javascript call PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am editing wordpress post template. And I want to call the PHP function in javascript, but my code doesn't work.

1. Here is what I want to do. When the user click the `OK button`, it should be showed a alert box when calling the PHP function success or failed. 
   [image]

Here is my js code:

```
(function() {
tinymce.PluginManager.add('facebook_api_tinymce', function( editor, url ) {
    editor.addButton( 'facebook_api_tinymce', 
            {
        title: 'Set friend condition', 
                    text: 'Condition',
                    type: 'menubutton',
                     menu: 
                     [    
                         {
                             text: 'Friend',
                              onclick: function() {
                                 editor.windowManager.open( {
                                     body:[
                                          {
                                            type: 'textbox',
                                            name: 'textboxName',
                                            label: 'Set friend',
                                            value: '20'     
                                          }
                                        ],onsubmit: function( e ) {

                                           $.ajax({
                                                url: 'databaseConnection.php',
                                                type: 'GET',
                                                data: {functionname: 'updateDatabase', post_id: 1, no_friend: 2},
                                                error:function(){
                                                   alert("failed");

                                                },
                                                success: function(data) {
                                                    alert("success");
                                                    console.log(data); // Inspect this in your console
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }

                                });    
                              }

                          }
                     ]

    });

});
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
<?php


$post_id = 0;
$no_friend = 0;

//Check did it pass the functionName
if( !isset($_POST['functionname']))
      $error = 'No function name!'; 


//Check did it pass the Post id
if( !isset($_POST['post_id']) ) 
     $error = 'No function post_id!';
 else {
     $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
 }

//Check did it pass the no_friend
if( !isset($_POST['no_friend']) ) 
     $error = 'No function no_friend!'; 
else{
    $no_friend = $_POST['no_friend'];
}


//If no data are missed
if( !isset( $error) ) {

    switch($_POST['functionname']) {
        case 'updateDatabase':

            updateDatabase(intval($post_id), intval($no_friend));
            break;

        default:
           $error = 'Not found function '.$_POST['functionname'].'!';
           break;
    }

}



function updateDatabase($post_id, $no_friend)
{
    $ans = $post_id + $no_friend;
    echo $ans;

}

echo $error;
```

It should show an alert box. What I am going wrong?

Comment: You are using `Type:"GET"` in ajax but you are trying to get value in php using `POST`

Comment: Thx a lot. problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you get back from you Ajax call? So what does this

```
console.log(data); // Inspect this in your console
```

actually show? If it's a whole built up Wordpress page, then maybe your PHP functions work, but they are never executed. This might be due to .htaccess rewrites and such.

Comment: It showed now when I used `jQuery.ajax` But , I printed the error that show no anything passed to PHP. What wrong is it? thx.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Type:"GET"` in ajax but you are trying to get value in php using `POST`

Just Change Your `Type:"GET"` to `Type:"POST"` in ajax or

Change `POST` to `GET` in php code